# Wobbly Glass Artifact in Render

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, glass

AMD 6700XT. I don't know what happened to my render, trying to figure out, I use standard BSDF Glass material. It is denoising problem or what?

[image]

Comment: Most likely denoising artifacts. Either pump up the samples or remove denoising in your render

Comment: @Gorgious wah, thanks for helping. Make my render to 4096 samples then the artifact gone, but significantly increase the render time. Must be patient then.